# org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/mem:db.trace.db", cause: "java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /mem:db.trace.db: Read-only file system"

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Trying to do testing on a springboot project and get this when I run the applicationTests

```
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/mem:db.trace.db", cause: "java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /mem:db.trace.db: Read-only file system" [90034-214]
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/mem:db.trace.db", cause: "java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /mem:db.trace.db: Read-only file system" [90034-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.logWritingError(TraceSystem.java:294)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.openWriter(TraceSystem.java:315)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.writeFile(TraceSystem.java:263)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.write(TraceSystem.java:247)
    at org.h2.message.Trace.error(Trace.java:173)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.setBackgroundException(Database.java:1791)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.Store.lambda$new$0(Store.java:125)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.handleException(MVStore.java:3318)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.panic(MVStore.java:593)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:469)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:4082)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.Store.<init>(Store.java:136)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:324)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:92)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:222)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:201)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:338)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:122)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:59)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100)
```

Not sure at all what is going on. First time trying to implement testing on SpringBoot, or java in general.
Below is the properties file for the tests

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2://mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
server.error.include-message=always
```

Comment: My first thought is that the forward slash (`/`) at the beginning makes H2 interpret it as a file, while `mem` suggests it should be an in-memory database. Try removing the char from the string. It would be easier to help if you attached your configuration to the question as it's not clear where the value comes from.

Comment: This solved the issue. Removed the // and the below worked
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

Answer (score 2):

The forward slash (`/`) at the beginning makes H2 interpret it as a file, while `mem` suggests it should be an in-memory database. Try removing the char from the string.